# How to load binary files with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

How to load binary files  (pdf, xls, other...) with Logstash and not changing their content.

Currently I try to load with

```
input {
file {
    path => "C:/path/files/*"
    type => "gesamt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
}
}
filter {    
   multiline {
      pattern => "/.*./gesamt"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
  }

base64 {
    field => "blob"   
}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "index-name"
    pipeline=>"test-pipeline"
 }
}
```

It seems that multiline filter damages the binary content.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just dump binary files into Elasticsearch, this will not make them searchable, and a filesystem might be better suited to hold them.

If you want to make them searchable, you might want to take a look at the [ingest attachment processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.5/ingest-attachment.html)

Comment: There is a test-pipeline that uses ingest attachment that works fine. The question was how to load the pdf(or others files) with logstash as binary without damaging them, before sending them to elasticsearch?

Comment: logstash only works with certain [codecs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/codec-plugins.html), but not for binary files